# Как переключаться между вкладками без TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я сделал свой "TabControl", но осталось сделать переключение между вкладками. Приложение разбито на два Gridа:левый и правый(видно на картинке). Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку слева открывалась конкретная вкладка справа. То есть кнопка и вкладка в разных Gridах. Как это можно реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит `сделал свой "TabControl"`.? Приложите в вопрос код xaml.

Comment: @mik.ov, имеется в виду то, что я сделал кнопки, которые должны переходить в конкретные вкладки. Код очень большой

Comment: Да не может он быть большим, удалите оттуда все стили, у вас там всего то несколько кнопок, и 3 Grid, примерно.

Comment: Почему вы никак не отреагировали на ответ, данный мной вам ранее?

Comment: @aepot, да, только сейчас увидел, что мой комментарий на Ваш ответ не отослался. EvgeniyZ предложил вариант, который в итоге сработал. Но Ваш код мне поможет в будущем, поэтому все ок, спасибо большое!)

Comment: @Костя в любом случае, если ответ был полезен, то примите его. Я спустя некоторое время удаляю бесполезные ответы.